# Java: Both if and else statements run

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am trying to refector a 2D array project to include a search method to clean up the code in my main method. However, when I enter a valid name it can find the first row of data but will also print the else statement. If I enter a valid name for second row it will sometimes return it after printing the else statement.

I've tried rewriting the code, creating a return variable for the method, using a nested loop, modifying the return array value.

```
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("====  Family Affair  ====");
    System.out.println("How many members will you add?");
    int number = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();//scan.nextLine() ad hoc scan fix
    //2D Array number of rows by scan/number input
    String[][] familyData = new String[number][2];
    //for loop captures input column data for each row
    //nested loop created duplicate output
    for (int i = 0; i < familyData.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("\tName: ");
        familyData[i][0] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\tState: ");
        familyData[i][1] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");//extra space

    printData(familyData);//call printData() method
     findData(familyData);//call findData() method
}
public static void printData(String[][] data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("\tName: " + data[i][0] + " ");
        System.out.print("\tState: " + data[i][1] + " ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
public static String[] findData(String[][] data) {
    System.out.println("SEARCH...");
    System.out.println("First Name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    String[] resultData = new String[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (name.equals(data[i][0])) {
            System.out.println("--- Search Results ---");
            System.out.println("\tName: " + data[i][0]);
            System.out.println("\tState: " + data[i][1]);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Nothing found. Try Again");
            System.out.println("First Name: ");
            name = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return resultData; //returned as String[] results = findData(param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest the use of [List<>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

private static List<String[]> findData(String[][] source, String search)
{
    final List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String[] array : source)
    {
        if (search.equals(array[0]))
        {
            data.add(array);
        }
    }
    
    return data;
}
```

And here is an example of use

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  String[][] familyData = new String[2][2];
  
  familyData[0][0] = "Sulabha";
  familyData[0][1] = "Married";
  
  familyData[1][0] = "Bertram";
  familyData[1][1] = "Single";
  
  List<String[]> data = findData(familyData, "Sulabha");
  
  if (data.size() == 0)
  {
      System.out.println("Nothing found.");
  }
  else
  {
      for (String[] item : data)
      {
          System.out.println("--- Search Results ---");
          System.out.println("\tName: "  + item[0]);
          System.out.println("\tState: " + item[1]);   
      }
  }
}
```